# Windows 7 cannot access network PC

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking

I am using Windows 7 on all my PCs and I have all PC networked & join as homegroup. Most of the time file sharing and accessing other PC works fine. But it is also frequently that sometime having trouble to access other PC even know that PC is show in Network. When double click on that PC icon, windows will popup error "Windows cannot access \NETPC". This cost us huge inconvenient to access files from other PC.

Why is it having trouble to access sometimes? How can I solve it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen due to a number of causes:
 1. Firewalls (either the built-in Windows Firewall, or third-party software) blocking network communication. This is the **most common cause** of these types of issues.
 2. Bad or improper network configuration. All the PCs in the network should be using DHCP.
 3. (Rarely) bad networking hardware or cables.

I hate to say it, but sometimes these types of problems are best chalked up to "Windows network sharing is terrible". If you're not opposed to it and it's appropriate for the environment, install Dropbox on all of the computers (it just works!). If you are in a corporate environment or another scenario where you need to restrict access based on user credentials or other security, use a file server solution instead.